# Does Rails Tutorial still works?

Tags: railstutorial.org

Is it problem at my side, or Hartl's Rails Tutorial doesn't work any more? I tried like 20 times, cleared cache and history and nothing happens..
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT is what console tells me..
railstutorial.org/book[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but i cant view book from Europe(I tried from Serbia, France and England). I entered site when i established VPN connection with server in Chicago USA.

Answer (score 1):

No, it may be you. I can get to it fine from the SE US. Try a deep link: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-mvc_in_action and see if it works.